# ASP.NET simple  div position

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to show a `div` like in this image (top), but I have this ugly version (bottom):

[image]

At the moment I am using this code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DataViewer" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <div style='border: 0px; width:600px;'><%# Eval("DriverId") %>
        <div style='border: 3px solid black; width:<%# Eval("OrderCount") %>cm;'><%# Eval("OrderCount") %>
            <div style='border: 0px; background-color: red; width:<%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %>%;'>
            <%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <%# Eval("DriverId") %>
>   %;'><%# Eval("OrderCount") %>             %;'>             <%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %>

you must use '%' instead of cm.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: changed the cm to %...still the same:(

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style='border: 0px; width:600px;'><%# Eval("DriverId") %>
    <div style='border: 3px solid black; width:<%# Eval("OrderCount")
```

Something wrong there with syntax because color mismatched. In this case its better to delete this tag and write it again.

Comment: i don't understand, what is mismatched?